# Execute kotlin files with extension other than kt

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin documentation I found, the kotlin file extension is always `.kt`

E.g. [Source file names](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html):

> If a Kotlin file contains a single class (potentially with related top-level declarations), its name should be the same as the name of the class, **with the .kt extension appended**

Can kotlin execute files with kotlin code, but with extension other than kt?

When I tried to change extenstion I get an error:

```
error: source entry is not a Kotlin file:
```

Comment: Just wondering why do need custom file extension?

Comment: Technically, you don't execute `.kt` files; they're source code.  In the case of Kotlin/JVM, they get compiled to `.class` files, and it's _those_ that get executed by the JVM.  (Possibly after being bundled into `.jar` or `.war` files.)  On the other hand, `.kts` script files _do_ get executed.  (Or at least, they get compiled and then executed in one step, without generating any other files.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a quick look at the compiler source code and found the following ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.3.41/compiler/cli/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/jvm/compiler/coreEnvironmentUtils.kt#L60)):

```
if (!vFile.isDirectory && vFile.fileType != KotlinFileType.INSTANCE) {
    configuration.report(CompilerMessageSeverity.ERROR, "Source entry is not a Kotlin file: $sourceRootPath", reportLocation)
    continue
}
```

Where `vFile.fileType` is retrieved [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/da373a0a3c2ff03e928937bc763c138acf0432fc/platform/core-impl/src/com/intellij/core/CoreFileTypeRegistry.java#L72) **based on the file extension**, which is declared in [KotlinFileType](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/v1.3.41/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/KotlinFileType.java) to be `kt`.

So basically I think you can't have Kotlin files with extensions other than `.kt`, otherwise the compiler will throw an error.

Comment: Strange they named method as default `getDefaultExtension`, but it's the only option

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, that would make sense if there were also something like "getAlternativeExtensions" or something like that